# Installing waymo opendataset on windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I am trying to install waymo open dataset in the windows environment. However when I try I get the following error:

`(python3.6) C:\Users\19729>pip install waymo-open-dataset-tf-2-3-0 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement waymo-open-dataset-tf-2-3-0 (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for waymo-open-dataset-tf-2-3-0`

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code does not show any error when I tried this in colab with `TensorFlow 2.7`.

However you can try again using below code :

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install waymo-open-dataset-tf-2-6-0 --user  # for tf 2.6.0.  OR
pip3 install waymo-open-dataset-tf-2-5-0 --user  # for tf 2.5.0.  OR
pip3 install waymo-open-dataset-tf-2-4-0 --user  # for tf 2.4.0.
```

You can also load this `built-in tensorflow dataset` from `tensorflow_datasets` using:

```
!pip install tensorflow_datasets

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow_datasets.object_detection import WaymoOpenDataset
ds = tfds.load('waymo_open_dataset', split='train', shuffle_files=True)
```

**Note**: This may take some time as it is [336.62 GiB](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/waymo_open_dataset) dataset.

There are some `waymo_open_datasets` also available in [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets?search=waymo).

Answer (score 0):

As of 14/06/2023 waymo_open_dataset has no windows distribution for the service. You either use a visual machine or a docker file.